# Как сериализовать такие объекты?

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация

Использую LoveCS в котором есть класс Image который я хотел бы сериализовать, но не получается :\

```
public class Game : Scene
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ImageSeriazable imgs = new ImageSeriazable(Graphics.NewImage("res/ava.png"));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("resources.data", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, imgs);
        fs.Close();
    }

    [Serializable]
    class ImageSeriazable
    {
        public Image img;
        public ImageSeriazable(Image i)
        {
            img = i;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сериализуйте путь к картинке, а не image

Comment: @FoggyFinder Я хотел бы запаковать файлы изображений в один файл без применения Архивов

Comment: base64 - вам в помощь